# Universal PAN id in zigbee

Tags: zigbee

Is there any Universal PAN id in zigbee which can receive packets from different PAN id senders?(For sending packets to all PANid we can use oxFFFF)

Answer (score 0):

ZigBee document 075297r04 is the "Proposal for Inter-PAN Exchange of Data in ZigBee".  You'll need to be a member of the ZigBee Alliance to access that though.

Inter-PAN is mentioned in a few specs, but I have not seen it in use yet.  You'll want to check with your hardware/stack provider to see how they support it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use "groups". Controling at the and all devices that joined this group.